# Send a request to call a function from another server

Tags: php, javascript, request

I have client code in php and two servers e.g apache and tomcat. I want to call a method in tomcat server through apache. Whereas apache is running in 81 port and tomcat is running in 85 port. 
the function which should be called is in javascript(in tomcat) . what is the php code to do this?

Am new to this please help me with explanation.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can do something like that:

```
<script src="yourscript.php" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

where 'yourscript.php' is:

```
<?php
header('Content-Type: application/javascript');
echo file_get_contents("http://yourtomcat:85/yourjsfile.js");
?>
```